# Oracle SQL Query to fetch non-working hours in a given month

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Need your help to frame a Oracle SQL query to capture non-working hours in a given month for the list of trips.

Values passed will be start date and end date

E.g.:

```
Feb has totally 696 hrs
     Start Date        End Date 
S2 - 02-Feb-16 14:00 - 06-Feb-16 20:00 - 102hrs
S1 - 01-Feb-16 04:00 - 02-Feb-16 10:00 - 30hrs

                    Total Worked hrs   - 132 hrs

The query result expected is 564 hrs
```

Attempted Query:

```
SELECT (a)
FROM   (
  SELECT COUNT( (SELECT DISTINCT 'O'
                 FROM   TRIP s,
                        TRUCK p
                 WHERE  s.TRUCKID = p.TRUCKID
                 AND    p.NOTES2='ABC'
                 AND    p.TRUCKID='553'
                 AND    ( to_date(d,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24')
                          NOT BETWEEN to_date(s.STIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24')
                          AND to_date(s.ETIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24')
                        )
               ) ) a
  FROM  (
    SELECT (TRUNC(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'MM') + level - 1) d
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')),'DD')
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried something like this but not able to convert into hrs.

SELECT (a) FROM (SELECT COUNT((SELECT DISTINCT 'O' FROM TRIP s,TRUCK p 
WHERE s.TRUCKID=p.TRUCKID 
AND p.NOTES2='ABC' 
AND p.TRUCKID='553'
AND (to_date(d,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24') NOT BETWEEN to_date(s.STIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24') AND to_date(s.ETIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24')))) a 
FROM (SELECT (TRUNC(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'MM') + level - 1) d 
FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')),'DD')))

Comment: Post your best effort so far and explain where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Put your code (use [edit]) into your question.

Comment: I tried something like below but challenge is not able to get values in hours, the below query retrieves in count of days

Code:
SELECT (a) FROM (SELECT COUNT((SELECT DISTINCT 'O' FROM TRIP s,TRUCK p 
WHERE s.TRUCKID=p.TRUCKID 
AND p.NOTES2='ABC' 
AND p.TRUCKID='553'
AND (to_date(d,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24') NOT BETWEEN to_date(s.STIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24') AND to_date(s.ETIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24')))) a 
FROM (SELECT (TRUNC(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'MM') + level - 1) d 
FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')),'DD')))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Trip_Dates ( Start_Date, End_Date ) AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE( '2016-02-02 14:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ), TO_DATE( '2016-02-06 20:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE( '2016-02-01 04:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ), TO_DATE( '2016-02-02 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
         - SUM( End_Date - Start_Date ) ) * 24 AS Unworked_Hours
FROM   Trip_Dates;
```

**Outputs**:

```
UNWORKED_HOURS
--------------
           564
```

Comment: Hi... The above query works fine, but I have 2 gaps
1. If there are any overlap of time, then those are also considered
2. If start time is in Jan and end time is in Feb, then also, it considers on the query. Ideally, only no. of days in Jan need to be considered

Please help